# How to ask your boss why he didnt give you a task?

Tags: management, employer-relations

Half a year ago I was moved to a project because of my expertise in a technology. The idea was to teach the team and focus mainly on using that technology from now on... But that project was rejected for various reasons. So I stayed in that project working on something that I was total newbie at. But now we finally received a project based on technology that I am expert with and surprise surprise my boss gives it to some one who have very little idea.

Should I talk to him ? How can I ask why without questioning his decision?

Comment: General tip: Never ask why you did not give me X? Rather, ask, why am I not part of X? Takes the offesive "edge" off the questions.

Comment: How was your own schedule? Are you needed for something else more important? Have you ruled out that your boss gave the task to a 'newbie' to help them learn the technology involved?

Comment: @Kozaky nope I quite bored (I look at what I can impruve in alredy existing proceses) I tell hime that like several times every day. No I was tol that by him and my supervisor also I am the only one with experience in that.

Comment: @SouravGhosh thanks for adivice but I cant ask that in these case as this project will requiere just one person.

Comment: Even better than being assigned the right task is choosing the tasks you find to be urgent and/or interesting, based on your expertise and your knowledge of the team's plan. Do you think your boss would be open to a more modern approach to management, e.g. one of the Agile frameworks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *Should I talk to him ? How can I ask why without questioning his decision?*

Yes. You should not question about his decision, question about plan for your future work and assignments in way that "hints" about your interest.

If I were you, I'd probably start a conversation saying:

> *"Hey Boss, I noticed that we got a new work assignment / project which is based on XYZ and it's good. It just happens to be there that after the last movement of mine into the current project, I am learning PQR and since it's been 6 months now, I can say I grew certain level of fluency and a natural interest about working with PQR.*
>
> *However, as you know, my primary skill in on XYZ and I was wondering about any possibilities of new work assignment with XYZ in near future? Also, If I am able to help in the existing project in any way, please let me know"*.

This should get the job done without "questioning" the decision about the allocation. Also, this will serve as a reminder about your skill-set, and your willingness to work with your preferred technology, in case it fell through the crack. In case there is a valid reason for not granting you the new task - you'll be enlightened about that, too.

Comment: @Erik Right, updated my answer, I too seem to have missed one point.

Answer (score 2):

> Should I talk to him ?

Yep.  It bothered you enough to post the question here, I would think it is worth a conversation with your manager.

> How can I ask why without questioning his decision?

Well, any way you go about this step, you are *sort of* questioning their decision.  This **should** be okay, as long as it is done in a respectful way.

"*Hey BOSS, I was curious to understand why XXXXXXXXXX*?"

The key to this not going badly will be your **tone**.  Keep it *respectful*, and you should be fine.